# VB.net VB JSON Serialization Issues

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to grab a volume freight load rate request from a freight carrier. It works fine except when I add an accessorial service request like "Appointment Delivery" The carriers system isnt picking up my added accesorial request (See serviceOps last part of request) .  They , the carrier, says this JSON request works.

```
{"login":{"username":"2xxx","password":"pwxxxxx","busId":"xxxxxx91606","busRole":"Third Party","paymentTerms":"Prepaid"},"details":{"serviceClass":"SPOT","typeQuery":"QUOTE","pickupDate":"20200615","acceptTerms":"true"},"originLocation":{"city":"KNOXVILLE","state":"TN","postalCode":"37918","country":"USA"},"destinationLocation":{"city":"ATLANTA","state":"GA","postalCode":"30369","country":"USA"},"listOfCommodities":{"commodity":[{"packageLength":48,"packageWidth":42,"packageHeight":62,"weight":3500,"handlingUnits":3,"packageCode":"PLT"},{"packageLength":48,"packageWidth":42,"packageHeight":42,"weight":2500,"handlingUnits":3,"packageCode":"PLT"}]},"serviceOptions":{"accOptions":"APPT"}}
```

When I send in my request it looks like this:

```
{"login":{"username":"2222","password":"pw422221","busId":"11206091606","busRole":"Third Party","paymentTerms":"Prepaid"},"details":{"serviceClass":"STD","typeQuery":"QUOTE","pickupDate":"20200424","productCode":"DFQ"},"originLocation":{"city":"Knoxville","state":"TN","postalCode":"37918","country":"USA","locationType":"COMM"},"destinationLocation":{"city":"Dallas","state":"TX","postalCode":"75206","country":"USA","locationType":"COMM"},"listOfCommodities":{"commodity":[{"packageLength":48,"packageWidth":42,"packageHeight":32,"weight":3600,"handlingUnits":1,"packageCode":"SKD"}]},"ServiceOpts":{"serviceOpts":["APPT"]}}
```

This is my 1st JSON project so I'm a little lost on how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting a response back but it's not showing any accessorial charge for the APPT.

```
Protected Sub grabspotrate()
    Dim SpotQuote As New fgtload

    SpotQuote.login = New fgtLoginData With { 'Create Login Data
    .username = "xxx",
    .password = "pwxxxxxx",
    .busId = "ZZZZZZZZ",
    .busRole = "Third Party",
    .paymentTerms = "Prepaid"
    }

    SpotQuote.details = New fgtDetailsData With { 'Create Details
    .serviceClass = "SPOT",
    .typeQuery = "QUOTE",
    .pickupDate = "20200616",
    .acceptTerms = "true"
}

    SpotQuote.originLocation = New fgtLocationnData With { 'Create Origin
    .city = "Knoxville",
    .state = "TN",
    .postalCode = "37918",
    .country = "USA",
    .locationType = "COMM"
}

    SpotQuote.destinationLocation = New fgtLocationnData With { 'Create Destination
    .city = "Atlanta",
    .state = "GA",
    .postalCode = "30369",
    .country = "USA",
    .locationType = "COMM"
}

    Dim Commodity1 As New fgtCommodity

    With Commodity1
        .nmfcClass = 65
        .packageLength = 48
        .packageWidth = 42
        .packageHeight = 65
        .weight = 7000
        .handlingUnits = 6
        .packageCode = "PLT"
    End With

    SpotQuote.listOfCommodities.commodity.Add(Commodity1)


    Dim serviceOpts As New serviceOptions With {
        .accOptions = ("APPT")
        }

    SpotQuote.ServiceOpts.serviceOpts.Add(serviceOpts)


    Dim Json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SpotQuote)

    Dim jsonDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json)
    Dim Url As String = ("https://api.yrc.com/node/api/ratequote")
    Dim Jsonresponse As String = Nothing

    Dim http As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.yrc.com/node/api/ratequote"), HttpWebRequest)
    http.Method = "POST"
    http.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    http.ContentType = "application/json"
    http.Timeout = 9500

    Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = Nothing


    sw = New System.IO.StreamWriter(http.GetRequestStream())

    sw.Write(Json.ToString())
    sw.Close()

    Try
        Dim httpResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(http.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Jsonresponse = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()


    Catch webExcp As WebException
        Dim rrmsg As String = webExcp.Message
        Dim status As WebExceptionStatus = webExcp.Status
    End Try

    Dim DFQ As quoteReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of quoteReturn)(Jsonresponse)
    Dim ratedcharge As Double = ((DFQ.pageRoot.bodyMain.rateQuote.ratedCharges.totalCharges) / 100)


End Sub

Public Class JSON_result
    Public isSuccess As Boolean

End Class


Public Class fgtload 'Primary wrapper
    Public login As New fgtLoginData
    Public details As New fgtDetailsData
    Public originLocation As New fgtLocationnData
    Public destinationLocation As New fgtLocationnData
    Public listOfCommodities As New fgtCommodityWrapper
    'Public serviceOpts As New serviceOptions
    Public ServiceOpts As New serviceOptionsWrapper
End Class
Public Class fgtLoginData 'Login Data
    Public username As String
    Public password As String
    Public busId As String
    Public busRole As String
    Public paymentTerms As String
End Class
Public Class fgtDetailsData 'Details Data
    Public serviceClass As String
    Public typeQuery As String
    Public pickupDate As String
    Public productCode As String
    Public acceptTerms As String
End Class
Public Class fgtLocationnData 'Location data for both Origin and Destination
    Public city As String
    Public state As String
    Public postalCode As String
    Public country As String
    Public locationType As String
End Class
Public Class fgtCommodityWrapper 'Commodity Data
    Public commodity As New List(Of fgtCommodity) ' Lists get serialized into arrays
End Class
Public Class fgtCommodity
    Public packageLength As Integer 'Doubles to allow floating-point numbers
    Public packageWidth As Integer
    Public packageHeight As Integer
    Public weight As Integer
    Public handlingUnits As Integer
    Public packageCode As String
    Public nmfcClass As Integer

End Class

Public Class serviceOptionsWrapper 'Commodity Data
    Public serviceOpts As New List(Of serviceOptions) ' Lists get serialized into arrays
End Class

Public Class serviceOptions
    Public accOptions As String
End Class
```

//////////////////////////////////////// Updated

I may have mistakenly flipped the two JSON statements up top. I have no issues with the JSON until I add the serviceOPts. Now I get a bad request because the brackets are missing around the "APPT". I was under the impresssion that brackets mean it's an array. I can submit up to 5 serviceOpts codes.   THis is what the carrier wants to see

```
  {
  "login": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "busId": "123456789123",
    "busRole": "Shipper",
    "paymentTerms": "Prepaid"
  },
  "details": {
    "serviceClass": "SPOT",
    "typeQuery": "QUOTE",
    "pickupDate": "20170713",
    "acceptTerms": true
  },
  "originLocation": {
    "city": "Nanuet",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10954",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "destinationLocation": {
    "city": "Olathe",
    "state": "KS",
    "postalCode": "66062",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "listOfCommodities": {
    "hazmatInd": false,
    "poisonInd": false,
    "commodity": [
      {
        "nmfcClass": 50,
        "handlingUnits": 1,
        "packageCode": "SKD",
        "packageLength": 48,
        "packageWidth": 48,
        "packageHeight": 48,
        "weight": 8000
      }
    ]
 },
  "serviceOpts": {
    "accOptions": [
      "APPT"
    ]
  }
}
```

The only issue Im having is with the last part serviceOpts.  I've tried every which way to get this to work. This is my 1st JSON attempt. How do I get it to place brackets around the code "APPT"?

Comment: It's mostly correct, except you have `Public locationType As String` in `fgtLocationnData` which is not present in the *model*. If the property doesn't exist, it may be ignored or it may be not, if the JSON object is validated. `Public ServiceOpts As New serviceOptionsWrapper` in  `fgtload` has instead a wrong name (it should be `serviceOptions`) and it's not an array, it's a single object, so change it in `Public serviceOptions As serviceOptionsObject` (or something else, rename your `serviceOptions` class to `serviceOptionsObject` or anything that fits).

Comment: Possibly, use auto-properties instead of fields.

Comment: In your first example, the carrier's `details` object contained `"acceptTerms":"true"`. Your example request was missing that property. Some places will reject the request if you haven't accepted terms.

Comment: Also, your object `ServiceOpts.serviceOpts` doesn't match their `serviceOptions.accOptions`.  They look different when serialized. It might get ignored by them because the names are not identical.

Comment: added some more info to the above question

Answer (score 0):

and the answer is..

Instead of  using:

```
Public Class accServiceOptions
    Public accOptions As string
End Class
```

I should have used this:

```
Public Class accServiceOptions
    Public accOptions As New List(Of [String])()
End Class
```

Thank you for all your inputs. I'm thinking I may have not asked the proper question.
This was my second shot at JSON and I am still a little shakey with it. I'm up and running now :)